# Live SASS Compiler not compiling in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, sass

I have a question about `Live SASS Compiler`. Once installed in VS Code, the bottom bar once showed "*watch sass*". But the code didn't compile. I deleted the files, created a new "main.scss", wrote the code, but the "watch sass" button does not appear. I tried uninstalling the extension and reinstalling it, but the buttom not show. What can be wrong?

[image]

Comment: did you try «Press F1 or ctrl+shift+P and enter `Live Sass: Watch Sass` to start watching and `Live Sass: Stop Watching Sass` to stop watching.»

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and use *Edit* to update your question accordingly.